# Placing an element visually after another, although in the DOM it appears first using Grid or Flexbox?

Tags: flexbox, accessibility, css-grid

I'm an accessibility expert, and my CSS has gotten quite rusty, but I need to quickly deliver an example for placing an element visually after the other, although in the DOM it is the other way round.

In the following code, the `<time>` element should visually appear **before** the heading, but for accessibility reasons, in the DOM it is placed after it.

```
<article>
  <h2>Wahlresultate bekannt gegeben</h2>
  <time datetime="2020-08-18">Dienstag, 18.8.2020</time>

  <p>Heute morgen wurden die Resultate der aktuellen Wahlen veröffentlicht.</p>
</article>
```

In early days, we needed to use hacky absolute positioning to achieve something like that. What should I use for this today? Flexbox? Grid? And how would it be accomplished?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with [Flex Box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox), specifically the [order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) property.

Be careful using this in every scenario though, having a visually different order to DOM order is normally an accessibility nono (although in this case it seems fine). Use it sparingly!

```css
article {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

h2 {
  order: 2;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}
time {
  order: 1;
}
p{
   order: 3;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <h2>Wahlresultate bekannt gegeben</h2>
  <time datetime="2020-08-18">Dienstag, 18.8.2020</time>

  <p>Heute morgen wurden die Resultate der aktuellen Wahlen veröffentlicht.</p>
</article>
```

To make it easier to control I would instead add a `<div>` around the elements you want to swap around and make that `display: flex`, this way you don't have to define the order of everything within the `article`.

I have included both versions incase you are unable to change the markup.

```css
.container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }

    h2 {
      order: 2;
      margin-top: 0.5em;
    }
    time {
      order: 1;
    }
```

```html
<article>
      <div class="container">
          <h2>Wahlresultate bekannt gegeben</h2>
          <time datetime="2020-08-18">Dienstag, 18.8.2020</time>
      </div>
      <p>Heute morgen wurden die Resultate der aktuellen Wahlen veröffentlicht.</p>
</article>
```

### Maximum compatibility

As this is marked as `accessibility` I would caution you on the use of flexbox. [Flexbox does not work in IE 8, 9 etc.](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

This is a problem because [a lot of screen reader users still use IE8, IE9, IE10 etc](https://webaim.org/projects/screenreadersurvey8/#browsers).

For that reason you should either use a [flexbox polyfill](https://github.com/jonathantneal/flexibility) or instead revert to using [absolute positioning as shown in this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/9zmcnedy/)

Comment: Thanks for your exhaustive explanation, @Graham! I think you added the wrong reference for your statement about screen reader users still using IE8; but the last [WebAIM survey](https://webaim.org/projects/screenreadersurvey8/#browsers) tells me differently anyway: only 2.1% still use IE6-8.

Comment: And what's the matter with having `margin-top: 0.51em ` on the `<h2>`?

Comment: Margin top was a mistake :-P I went back and edited the code to remove some extra stuff that wasn't needed. Also corrected the link, thanks for that. You have around 3.6% of users on IE 6-10. I would just have a separate style sheet for those users anyway if you wanted to use flexbox (well for IE9+ as at least you can use modern JS and reasonably modern CSS with IE9+). Obviously it is up to you what cut-off point you put on compatibility, we support IE9 but that doesn't mean everyone should, the web does need to evolve!!