# How to handle blog articles category labels not passing accessibility rules for labeling links that use the same text?

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria

Does anyone know how I should handle aria-labels on link labels that repeat dozens of time on a page? My website accessibility checker tool keeps flagging these elements as using the same link text for these labels and they require unique aria-labels. Problem is, all of the links go to the same generic pages and am not sure how to make the aria-labels specific enough.

Has anyone dealt with anything like this before and how did you handle it? I imagine I'd need a JS solution to inject aria-labels, but before I invest in a JS resource doing this for me does anyone know how I can make these specific enough to pass the checker but not confuse screen readers?

[Screenshot of category labels for each article](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCK8m.png)

Comment: Why do you give them aria-label tag? https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/ARIA14.html You shouldn't do this in your case

Comment: Because the tool keeps flagging the category links as having the same text. I feel like I have to add some aria-label to each category to pass the checker. So just a generic "View Press Releases" for all the press release links and do the same for the other categories as well. Thoughts?

Comment: Do all tags have the same links? And there are many of these links on one page?

Comment: Yes each category (Like Press Releases) all go to the press releases page. There could be as many as 20 or 30 of these on the page like in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for `aria-labels` and what you are doing is not an accessibility fail. You have to bear in mind the automated accessibility checkers are dumb (and in this case quite possibly wrong) and are only there to offer guidance on common accessibility fails.

The main reason you are seeing this is that the accessibility checker thinks that this is text like "read more" that is not descriptive of the end-point. It should pick up the fact that the end-point is the same but it obviously does not.

Using the same link text for links that go to the same page is **encouraged**:

> It is a best practice for links with the same destination to have
> consistent descriptions (and this is a requirement per Success
> Criterion 3.2.4 for pages in a set). It is also a best practice for
> links with different purposes and destinations to have different
> descriptions.
>
> Source: https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/navigation-mechanisms-refs.html

Also one of the checks for [success criterion 3.2.4 - Consistent Identification](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/consistent-identification) is:

> Check that this associated text is identical for each user interface
> component with the same function.
>
> Source: https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Techniques/general/G197.html

Assuming your articles are marked-up correctly a screen reader user could skip between headings (`<h2>`s for example) in order to not hear the same category links. This is one of the primary ways a screen reader user will navigate a page (via headings).

**For this reason the categories should be AFTER the heading in the HTML so that they are read out after the heading.**

[You could place the heading **visually** after the tags using techniques similar to those in this answer I gave.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63467636/2702894) This would be acceptable for "logical tab order" in my opinion so you wouldn't fail there.

Your only other option would be to use `aria-hidden="true"` and `tabindex="-1"` on your category links to hide them from screen reader users and take them out of the tab order. If you did this you would need to ensure a categories list is available at the side of the page.

Personally I would go with the first option as the categories information is useful to screen reader users, the fact the links repeat themselves over and over if I search by links would indicate they are categories to me when using a screen reader anyway.

Comment: My opinion is not to leave duplicates, you can specify explicitly that the link is a category: <a href="#"><span class="sr-only">Link to category</span> Salads</a>

Comment: Yes but the information is useful, I might want to know what category a post is in, by doing what you said I then remove that information from the post. It is a difficult one to get right as the golden rule of accessibility is to offer "as similar an experience as possible to everyone", but at the same time multiple links could be annoying, hence why I suggested the different order so screen reader users could use headings to avoid the replication, people with mobility issues however would unfortunately have to put up with repeated links, it is a fair tradeoff in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it is correct to hide all duplicate links except for the first element that contains these labels

You force people with disabilities to navigate through all the same links using keyboard navigation, this is also bad for a screen reader

1.) Hide any duplicate labels from your screen reader

```
aria-hidden="true"
```

2.) Hide any duplicate labels from keyboard navigation

```
tabindex="-1"
```

**Note!** don't forget to leave one unique link! You can also hide everything and add them to context under elements or above elements. When I say hide, I mean the above methods.

---

It's easy to check for accessibility, close your eyes and imagine you click on a tab and hear (in a screen reader) a re-link through every two elements! This is annoying isn't it?